# How do I install PRIVATE FILE_SET files in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have added some headers to a library target with the following snippet:

```
target_sources(${project_lib} 
               PRIVATE ${source}
               PRIVATE FILE_SET HEADERS FILES ${headers})
```

This works fine, but I am unable to export these headers files to the install include directory. The following snippet does not export anything to the quoted directory:

```
install(TARGETS ${project_lib} 
    EXPORT ${project_lib}Target
    FILE_SET HEADERS 
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${project_name})
```

If I change PRIVATE to PUBLIC, the export works, but it adds unwanted files to the public INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES variable.

My current approach consist in exporting the collected headers with a custom target. The collected headers are obtained with:

```
# Extract the list of headers from the target to export
get_target_property(exports ${project_lib} HEADER_SET)
list(TRANSFORM exports REPLACE "^${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/" "")
```

and copied to the CURRENT_BINARY_FOLDER. Finally, they are exported with the following command:

```
get_target_property(LIB_BINARY_DIR ${project_lib} BINARY_DIR)
install(DIRECTORY ${LIB_BINARY_DIR}/include TYPE INCLUDE)
```

This is also working, but I am sure that this solution is not the best one.

EDIT:
I found a third approach, I could still add the HEADERS as PUBLIC, and just delete the unwanted directory from the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY:

```
get_target_property(include_dirs ${project_lib} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
list(REMOVE_ITEM include_dirs "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>")
set_target_properties(${project_lib} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${include_dirs}")
```